# Image positioning is inexact with 1-pixel images

Tags: graphics, positioning

This MWE has an unexpected shift with `1x1.png`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, mwe}
\newcommand{\ig}[1]{%
    \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=3cm]{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
    \ig{example-image-a.pdf}%
    \ig{example-image-a.pdf}%

    \nointerlineskip%
    % \ig{example-image-a.pdf}%
    % wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/1x1.png
    \ig{1x1.png}%
    \ig{example-image-a.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

This is with four `example-image-a.pdf`:

[image]

And this is with the bottom-left one replaced with a 1x1-pixel image:

[image]

Is that due to numerical inaccuracies? What can I do to improve this situation, apart from using larger images? Is there a minimum size that I should avoid going below for `pdflatex`? Should I use as-large-as-possible images?

Comment: How is 1px defined in the LaTeX world? How is it even defined in the rest of the world. Isn't it just related to screen size

Comment: @daleif that's true but a red herring, the fact is that if you scale images of different sizes to be 3cm wide using `\includegraphics` then there is no guarantee that the two images are exactly the same width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arithmetic in `graphicx` was never designed to give 1-pixel accuracy, but since you know what result you want by scaling the pixel image you can force that to be true.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\ig}[1]{%
    \includegraphics[height=3cm, width=3cm]{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\sbox0{\ig{example-image-a.pdf}}
\sbox2{\ig{1x1.png}}
\typeout{ht \the\ht0=\the\ht2}
\typeout{dp \the\dp0=\the\dp2}
\typeout{wd \the\wd0=\the\wd2}
\ht2=\ht0 % not needed here but can't hurt
\dp2=\dp0 % not needed here but can't hurt
\wd2=\wd0 % numerical accuracy
    \ig{example-image-a.pdf}%
    \ig{example-image-a.pdf}%

    \nointerlineskip%
    % \ig{example-image-a.pdf}%
    % wget https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/1x1.png
    \usebox{2}%
    \ig{example-image-a.pdf}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But wouldn't simply setting the width to some fixed value without altering the underlying scaling calculations result in the second graphic of the second row overlapping the 1x1 pixel image instead of really fixing the scaling issue (though the effect would be in the sp-range)?

Comment: @Skillmon "in the sp range" means "not visible" (mostly), but yes. but the scaling isn't _wrong_ it is just that using fixed point TeX dimen arithmetic you can't expect that x * (3cm/x) =3cm exactly. Actually you can't expect that using _any_ numeric arithmetic (although for example l3fp would be a lot more accurate)